# Moving Pepper from a point to another

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I am trying to move Pepper from one point to another which involves a turn of 90 degrees and it is around  40 metres distance. I can make it work when there are no obstacles but when there are obstacles the Pepper stops and then we don't know his location to move again. I am using ALNavigation navigateTo method.

I have tried getting the position by using ALMotion getRobotPosition but it is very error prone and I don't know if we can use that while using ALNavigation API.

Please suggest any solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: GetRobotPosition will return the same position than when you ask to walk 40m. So if it works with enough precision without obstacles, it should work quite the same, even if an obstacle is detected.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, thanks will try that. Do you have any suggestions on doing autonomous navigation with Pepper? We have tried the exploration APIs but they don't perform well in larger maps narrow hallways. Also sometimes the robot gets lost even at start.

Comment: In the current API, only base sensors are used, so it doesn't fit well with large room (>4x4). Other suggestions: wait for next versions that will include better slam using more sensors or if you can't wait, develop your own software based on vision slam or ...

Comment: Thanks Alexandre

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use ALNavigationProxy::navigateToInMap.
You can play around with this example: https://github.com/aldebaran/naoqi_navigation_samples

1. Get the code from github or http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/exploration-api.html#exploration-api
   -see the sample code at the bottom of the page.
2. Map your space
3. ALNavigationProxy::navigateToInMap

Comment: Hi Anders, we have tried that but faced many issues such as sometimes it loses track of where it is even at the start when we provide the localization guess. Also when the things around it move that were initially in the map , it doesn't work as expected. Do you have any suggestions about how to improve the navigation?

Comment: You should help the robot by starting localization at the same position with easily recognizable geometry. But some offices are too hard for the robot.
There is nothing you can do if the robot encounters a static object, e.g. new furnture. But if a person blocked its path, you could implement a try/catch around the movement exception, do a wait and then try to localize from last known position on the map.